# Expectation of expectation of indicator function

Tags: probability, means

Is the following correct

$$E[E[\mathbb{I}(X)]] = E[\mathbb{I}(X)]$$

I assume that $E[E[X]] = E[X]$, as $E[X]$ is a number and expected value of a constant is a constant, and that $\mathbb{I}(X)$ has a binomial distribution. $\mathbb{I}(X)$ represents an indicator function of some random variable $X$.

Exact definition of $\mathbb{I}()$ is not important.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, $E[f(X)]$ is nonrandom, so $E[E[f(X)]] = E[f(X)]$ for any function $f$ for which the terms are well-defined.